# How to keep password protection to individual files/folders

Tags: release-freya, security

I am using elementary OS freya. How can I encrypt (or) keep password protection to individual files/folders.

The following are my requirements and what I have tried so far:

- The solution should be in GUI
- I have already tried `cryptkeeper` with no success.
- I have tried `ecryptfs-utils` from software center, but that is not GUI.
- I am not asking to hide, so keeping a `.` before file name *may* not be the solution.
- I don't want to use `chmod`

Answer (score 1):

For individual files, I usually just compress files as `.zip`, then enter a password to protect it. When you try to open the compressed file, it asks you for the password.